# Google Maps regional based clustering

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

let's say I have polygons of counties and several thousands of markers. Is it possible to check which marker goes to which polygon and then use clustering? Grid-based clustering and distance-based clustering don't fit my needs.

I haven't found any example of using this and I am not even sure whether it can be done. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require to use  [point on polygon function](http://jsfromhell.com/math/is-point-in-poly) as a basis.
If you loop through your marker array and use the function to find markers in the polygon

Comment: is there any working example available for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#poly) .

I guess that's what you're looking for: 
*Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.*

But it may take some time to calculate this, you better should cache the result somehow.